# Unbuffered XmlReader implementation

Tags: c#, .net, xml

does anyone know of an unbuffered XmlReader implementation?

Not the XmlTextReaderImpl which uses a byte[] buffer internally and reads from a stream at construction! I find this incredibly annoying. I only want the XmlReader to read when actually calling Read* on the object. Not to buffer data or similar.

NOTE: I am not talking about cached vs non-cached. But stream buffering, which happens internally in the XmlTextReader for example.

I want to use this in a scenario where I currently have to create a new XmlTextReader each time I want to deserialize an object, but since this creates a buffer of size 4096 every time it puts a lot of pressure on the garbage collector. So I would like to keep an instance of the XmlReader around (which can continously read from a stream of xml objects), but this is not possible with the BCL implementation or have an XmlReader that does not create a buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not creating a buffer coule be impossible.

The parser needs to have lookahead, not to mention NameTables for fast processing.

4096 seems big, but might be the most efficient unit: it coincides with a page of virtual memory, and it could be used *in stead of* many repeated small allocations (? guessing)

However, reusing the instance would have been nice. You could have a look at the mono implementation and work it to your liking:

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml/XmlTextReader.cs

Comment: thanks for your reply. of course, implement your own XmlTextReader is an option, but I do not think it is a real option, since this would require maintaining this very complex class etc. So I was hoping for a better answer, something like resetting the XmlTextReader or similar...

Comment: @harrydev: if you are actually wrapping your readers in `using()` blocks, I'd be heavily surprised if any of this would make any difference. Did you actually profile things? I mean it is nice to look at the GC stats, but it doesn't signify anything if it is mad fast (which it probably is, in the context of XML serialization anyway)...

Comment: Yes, I measured this and used profiler (both cpu and allocation), and neglecting the GC impact is not a good idea. If I am serializing 1000000 objects this means 4 GB of memory is allocated, which makes a huge impact on the GC, even if most of it may be collected on Gen 0. Just the clearing of the 4 KB alone takes time. And we are trying to avoid unwanted GC collections to occur, since this will introduce unwanted latency.

Comment: Nowhere near 4GB will be allocated _unless_ all serialization takes place concurrently or you forget to dispose the readers early? Again, I doubt whether the alarming heap profile data has any real life performance impact here. Perhaps I'll try it out comparatively later.

Comment: Yes all 4GB are allocated, not at the same time. That was not what I was saying. But 4 GB are allocated and has to be collected over time. That is a huge impact on GC and time spent in this.

Comment: @harrydev: that doesn't really make a lot of sense to me. Most everything in .NET is dynamically allocated. The allocations only pressure the heap if they are longlived or they fragment it . Assuming that they employ custom allocators recycling 4k blocks is going to be negligible regardless of the problem domain. Also, you're doing wholesome _XML serialization_ there. If this would be the bottleneck, you'd better switch to ProtoBuf.NET or something to get rid of it